# Agregar y eliminar de forma dinamica un div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito eliminar elementos `div` que se hacen a través de un `for` dinámicamente. Depende del numero que pongo es la cantidad de `div` que se agregan y esta perfecto, el problema es que no se como borrar un solo `div` sin que se borren todos los demás (Entiendo que el `for` es como que se reinicia y vuelve a cargar la cantidad pedida).

Básicamente si completo los `div` (Lo cual se completan buscando afiliados en una BD) y por ahí me equivoco, en vez de 4 `div` eran 3, si pongo 3 se borran todos los que ya estaban completados (Se reinicia el `for`).

Quiero buscar la forma de tener un botón para borrar solo el `div` agregado demás.

Y acá les paso la función de `javascript` que me muestra la cntidad de `div`, depende del número que pongo en "cantidad"

```js
function numafiliados (e) {
  
  const cantidad = $('#i-cant').val();  

  $('#d-afil-cant').empty();

  for (var i=1; i<=cantidad; i++) {
    var nuevo = '<div id="n'+i+'" style="display:flex"><div class="d-afiliado2">';
    nuevo +='<label class="l-busqueda" for="" >AFILIADO:'+i+'</label><span class="afiliados-s"></span></div>';
    nuevo += '<div class="d-afiliado2"><label class="l-busqueda" for="" id="numAfil'+i+'" style="margin-top:-4px;width:auto;">Numero Afiliado: </label><input type="text" id="i-afil'+i+'" name="AFILIADO'+i+'" class="i-afil2"> </div>'
    nuevo += '<div class="d-afiliado2"><label class="l-busqueda" for="" id="l-'+i+'"  >Honorario $:</label><span class="hon-afil-multi  sp-afil" id="hon-afil-multi"></span></div>'
    nuevo += '<div class="d-afiliado2"><label for="" class="l-busqueda" style="width:auto;">Honorario JUS:</label><span class="hon-jus sp-afil" id="hon-jus-multi"></span><label class="eliminar l-busqueda">X</label></div><br></div>'  
    nuevo += '<div class="d-afiliados"><span id="'+i+'" name="afiliado'+i+'" class="sp-naf sp-afil"></span></div>';

    $('#d-afil-cant').append(nuevo);
  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='contenedor-profesional'>
    <div id='profesional'>
        <div id='d-honreg'>
        <div> <label for='HONORARIO_REGULADO' class='l-busqueda' id='l-honreg'>Honorario regulado en pesos ($):</label> </div>
            <div><input type='number' step='any' id='HONORARIO_REGULADO' name='CJIMPO' onKeyPress='return acceptNum(event)' class='numero requerido' onfocusout='requerir(this)' onkeyup="saltar(event,'jus'), dividirHonorarios()" required> </div>
        </div>
        <div id='d-jus'>
            <div><label for='jus' id='l-jus' class='label2 label' >JUS:</label> <!--Un maximo de 4 caracteres hasta 2020 --></div>
            <div><input type='number' step='any' id='jus' name='JUS' class='numero requerido'  onKeyPress='return acceptNum(event)' onfocusout='requerir(this)'onkeyup="saltar(event,'i-ley'), dividirJUS()" required> <br></div>
            <div id='AñoJUS' style='color:red; position: absolute; left: 376px; top: 6px; font-size: 10.5px; font-weight: 600;'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='d-ley'>
            <div><label id='l-ley' class='l-busqueda'>PROP LEY</label></div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" id='i-ley' name='PropLey'></div>
        </div>  
        <div id='d-cant'>
        <div><label id='l-cant' class='l-busqueda'>Cantidad</label></div>
        <div><input type="text" id='i-cant' value='1' disabled='disabled' maxlength='2' onKeyPress='return acceptNum(event)' onKeyup='numafiliados(),  numeroMaximo(this), dividirHonorarios(), dividirJUS()'></div>
        </div><br>
    </div>
    <div id="n1" style="display:flex">
        <div class="d-afiliado2">
        </div>
        <div class="d-afiliado2">
        <label class="l-busqueda" for="" id="numAfil1" style="margin-top:-4px;width:auto;">Numero Afiliado: </label>
        <input type="text" id="i-afil1" name="AFILIADO1" class="i-afil2"> 
    </div>
    <div class="d-afiliado2">
        <label class="l-busqueda" for="" id="l-1"  >Honorario $:</label>
        <span class="hon-afil-multi  sp-afil" id="hon-afil-multi"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="d-afiliado2">
        <label for="" class="l-busqueda" style="width:auto;">Honorario JUS:</label>
        <span class="hon-jus sp-afil" id="hon-jus-multi"></span>
        <label class="eliminar l-busqueda">X</label>
    </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="d-afiliados">
        <span id="1" name="afiliado1" class="sp-naf sp-afil"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

prueba el siguiente código:

## Código Javascript

```
function numafiliados (e) {
    const cantidad = $('#i-cant').val();  

    $('#d-afil-cant').empty();

    for (var i=1; i<=cantidad; i++) {
        var nuevo = '<div id="n'+i+'" class="afili" style="display:flex"><div class="d-afiliado2">';
        nuevo +='<label class="l-busqueda" for="" >AFILIADO:'+i+'</label><span class="afiliados-s"></span></div>';
        nuevo += '<div class="d-afiliado2"><label class="l-busqueda" for="" id="numAfil'+i+'" style="margin-top:-4px;width:auto;">Numero Afiliado: </label><input type="text" id="i-afil'+i+'" name="AFILIADO'+i+'" class="i-afil2"> </div>'
        nuevo += '<div class="d-afiliado2"><label class="l-busqueda" for="" id="l-'+i+'"  >Honorario $:</label><span class="hon-afil-multi  sp-afil" id="hon-afil-multi"></span></div>'
        nuevo += '<div class="d-afiliado2"><label for="" class="l-busqueda" style="width:auto;">Honorario JUS:</label><span class="hon-jus sp-afil" id="hon-jus-multi"></span><label class="eliminar l-busqueda">X</label></div><br></div>'  
        nuevo += '<div class="d-afiliados"><span id="'+i+'" name="afiliado'+i+'" class="sp-naf sp-afil"></span></div>';

        $('#d-afil-cant').append(nuevo);
    }
}

function removediv() {
    var count = 0;
    $("#d-afil-cant > .afili").each(function(){
        count = $("#d-afil-cant > .afili").length;

    });
    $("#n" + count).remove();
}
```

## Código HTML

```
<div class="d-afiliados">
    <input type="text" id="i-cant" placeholder="Ingrese números afiliados"></input>
</div><br/>

<div>
    <input type="button" id="Generar" onclick="numafiliados();" value="Generar" />
    <input type="button" id="DeleteLastRow" onclick="removediv();" value="Borrar última fila" />
</div>

<div id="d-afil-cant">
</div><br/>
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu aporte pues no estaría se más y haría más fácil entenderlo

Comment: Esta bien, la proxima sin falta 

Answer (score 1):

Buen dia, con esto puedes agregar y eliminar divs de manera dinamica.

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $('.remove').closest('.wrapper').find('.element').not(':first').last().remove();
});
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.clone', function() {
  $('.clone').closest('.wrapper').find('.element').first().clone().appendTo('.results');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
.element {
  background: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.buttons {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
  Hooolaaa
  </div>
  <div class="results"></div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="clone">Agregar</button>
    <button class="remove">Borrar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```